# Windows Server hardware change log?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hardware

Is there any simple way to monitor hardware changes on a Windows Server (2008). My host has added some memory to my server and i want to know exactly when that was done?

Comment: Did you try checking the event logs to see when the server was rebooted (assuming it needed to be rebooted after)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 2003 server the SYSTEM INFORMATION tool (start>all programs>accessories>system tools>System Information) can show you, by selecting "System History" from the view menu. I'm not sure if the same applies on 2008.

It also tracks changes on critical system files - useful in case a windows update breaks something and you need to know why.